# Given an eBay URL, is there some way to get Item details

Tags: ebay-api

Say I have a url, such as http://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry%20Potter%20and%20the%20Deathly%20Hallows%207%20by%20J.%20K.%20Rowling%20(2007,%201st%20Edition)/322028146082

I want to get the details of this item, but the API seams to require for me to know information like their productId, which I don't have. How would I go about this?

---

While coming to ask this question, I found my answer, but if anyone has any other input, I'd be grateful.

---

## Edit

So when I came to use this I realised I still haven't fully answered my own question. While I have details about the item's price etc, I cannot get the productID, or even something like a UPC, ASIN, EAN, ISBN or anything unless the listing has multiple variants, in which case it might be used to differentiate said variants. I'm still not sure whether this is possible, and if it is, why it is not featured more prominently in eBay's API help.

Comment: The item id is the 12 digit number at the end of the url, you can use regex to extract it. Then just use getsingleitem to pull the data that you need.

Comment: Yes, this is what I explained at length in my answer

Comment: Ha, sorry im guilty of not refreshing the page :)

Comment: @IsaacMontaine Not a problem, although what I have realised since is that the information I've retrieved still doesn't include a productId. I'm still not sure how I'd get this in order to use with the product API, as I'd ideally be able to find similar listings if the item I was looking at had ended...

Comment: Im guessing that you are looking for something that relates one item to another on eBay to say that they are same product. This doesn't really exist on eBay yet. There are some categories where there was an attempt to catalog the items, but for the most part you are at the mercy of the person who listed the item to provide something useful in the item specifics fields.

Comment: For a lot of items on sale on eBay this is true, however there is a product API which, given a productId, gives you the items currently on sale for that productId unfortunately as far as the API is concerned, this seems to be a one-way mapping

Comment: Well you can get the productid, but you just need to figure out the scope of your project first. And again you are at the mercy of the seller to have filled in a UPC, EAN or ISBN on the item as well as eBay to have created a  productid for it. But, you can use findItemsAdvanced, findItemsByKeywords, findItemsIneBayStores to extract productid's. One basic idea would be to take the title you have and pass it through findItemsByKeywords with a item filter on the seller and the price. Then you can use that productid with findItemsByProduct to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I see it, this should really be the first thing on the ePN docs, hence posting a question and answer here. I spent ages looking at the Product API and the Finding API, before it struck me that this is something you would need to be able to find out as a shopper.

You can get this information using the eBay shopping API's [GetSingleItem](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) method. This only requires knowledge of an [ItemID](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Request.ItemID), which is found in the URL. In the example, it's the number after the slash, however there are a few different URL formats, so it may be best to regex match for a 10+ digit number.

Once you have this the request is simple, for instance http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&itemId=322028146082&appid=[YOUR_APP_ID]&version=515 will give you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSingleItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2016-03-04T14:43:46.784Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Build>E949_CORE_APILW_17769283_R1</Build>
    <Version>949</Version>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>322028146082</ItemID>
        <EndTime>2016-04-03T13:41:26.000Z</EndTime>
        <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry-Potter-and-Deathly-Hallows-7-J-K-Rowling-2007-1st-Edition-/322028146082</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
        <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
        <Location>Kings Mountain, North Carolina</Location>
        <GalleryURL>http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/pict/3220281460828080_1.jpg</GalleryURL>
        <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMTY4/z/I~kAAOSwJb9WsVh9/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>
        <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFg5NDM=/z/l8sAAOSwpzdWsVie/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>
        <PrimaryCategoryID>171228</PrimaryCategoryID>
        <PrimaryCategoryName>Books:Fiction &amp; Literature</PrimaryCategoryName>
        <BidCount>0</BidCount>
        <ConvertedCurrentPrice currencyID="USD">12.5</ConvertedCurrentPrice>
        <ListingStatus>Active</ListingStatus>
        <TimeLeft>P29DT22H57M40S</TimeLeft>
        <Title>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows 7 by J. K. Rowling (2007, 1st Edition)</Title>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <AutoPay>true</AutoPay>
    </Item>
</GetSingleItemResponse>
```

If you need more information than this, there's the trading API, which is a little more complicated. For this you must make XML or SOAP POST requests on https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

Headers are like this:

```
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 949
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: [YOUR_APP_ID]
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: [YOUR_DEV_ID]
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: [YOUR_CERT_ID]
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetItem
X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0
```

Body is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>[YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ItemID>322028146082</ItemID>
</GetItemRequest>
```

Submitting this should give you a body like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2016-03-04T16:40:00.981Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>949</Version>
    <Build>E949_CORE_API_17775483_R1</Build>
    <Item>
        <AutoPay>true</AutoPay>
        <BuyerProtection>ItemIneligible</BuyerProtection>
        <BuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">0.0</BuyItNowPrice>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <GiftIcon>0</GiftIcon>
        <HitCounter>NoHitCounter</HitCounter>
        <ItemID>322028146082</ItemID>
        <ListingDetails>
            <Adult>false</Adult>
            <BindingAuction>false</BindingAuction>
            <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
            <ConvertedBuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">0.0</ConvertedBuyItNowPrice>
            <ConvertedStartPrice currencyID="USD">12.5</ConvertedStartPrice>
            <HasReservePrice>false</HasReservePrice>
            <StartTime>2016-03-04T13:41:26.000Z</StartTime>
            <EndTime>2016-04-03T13:41:26.000Z</EndTime>
            <ViewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry-Potter-and-Deathly-Hallows-7-J-K-Rowling-2007-1st-Edition-/322028146082</ViewItemURL>
            <HasUnansweredQuestions>false</HasUnansweredQuestions>
            <HasPublicMessages>false</HasPublicMessages>
            <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry-Potter-and-Deathly-Hallows-7-J-K-Rowling-2007-1st-Edition-/322028146082</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
        </ListingDetails>
        <ListingDuration>Days_30</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
        <Location>Kings Mountain, North Carolina</Location>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>171228</CategoryID>
            <CategoryName>Books:Fiction &amp; Literature</CategoryName>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <PrivateListing>false</PrivateListing>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ReviseStatus>
            <ItemRevised>true</ItemRevised>
        </ReviseStatus>
        <Seller>
            <AboutMePage>false</AboutMePage>
            <Email>Invalid Request</Email>
            <FeedbackScore>82</FeedbackScore>
            <PositiveFeedbackPercent>0.0</PositiveFeedbackPercent>
            <FeedbackPrivate>false</FeedbackPrivate>
            <FeedbackRatingStar>Blue</FeedbackRatingStar>
            <IDVerified>false</IDVerified>
            <eBayGoodStanding>true</eBayGoodStanding>
            <NewUser>false</NewUser>
            <RegistrationDate>2007-05-30T12:11:34.000Z</RegistrationDate>
            <Site>US</Site>
            <Status>Confirmed</Status>
            <UserID>westbrandbooks</UserID>
            <UserIDChanged>false</UserIDChanged>
            <UserIDLastChanged>2016-02-02T14:57:13.000Z</UserIDLastChanged>
            <VATStatus>NoVATTax</VATStatus>
            <SellerInfo>
                <AllowPaymentEdit>true</AllowPaymentEdit>
                <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
                <CIPBankAccountStored>false</CIPBankAccountStored>
                <GoodStanding>true</GoodStanding>
                <LiveAuctionAuthorized>false</LiveAuctionAuthorized>
                <MerchandizingPref>OptIn</MerchandizingPref>
                <QualifiesForB2BVAT>false</QualifiesForB2BVAT>
                <StoreOwner>false</StoreOwner>
                <SafePaymentExempt>false</SafePaymentExempt>
            </SellerInfo>
            <MotorsDealer>false</MotorsDealer>
        </Seller>
        <SellingStatus>
            <BidCount>0</BidCount>
            <BidIncrement currencyID="USD">0.0</BidIncrement>
            <ConvertedCurrentPrice currencyID="USD">12.5</ConvertedCurrentPrice>
            <CurrentPrice currencyID="USD">12.5</CurrentPrice>
            <MinimumToBid currencyID="USD">12.5</MinimumToBid>
            <QuantitySold>0</QuantitySold>
            <ReserveMet>true</ReserveMet>
            <SecondChanceEligible>false</SecondChanceEligible>
            <ListingStatus>Active</ListingStatus>
            <QuantitySoldByPickupInStore>0</QuantitySoldByPickupInStore>
        </SellingStatus>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
                <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>
            <SalesTax>
                <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
            </SalesTax>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>ShippingMethodStandard</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
                <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
            <ThirdPartyCheckout>false</ThirdPartyCheckout>
            <ShippingDiscountProfileID>0</ShippingDiscountProfileID>
            <InternationalShippingDiscountProfileID>0</InternationalShippingDiscountProfileID>
            <SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ShipToLocations>US</ShipToLocations>
        <Site>US</Site>
        <StartPrice currencyID="USD">12.5</StartPrice>
        <TimeLeft>P29DT21H1M26S</TimeLeft>
        <Title>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows 7 by J. K. Rowling (2007, 1st Edition)</Title>
        <HitCount>6</HitCount>
        <LocationDefaulted>true</LocationDefaulted>
        <GetItFast>false</GetItFast>
        <BuyerResponsibleForShipping>false</BuyerResponsibleForShipping>
        <PostalCode>28086</PostalCode>
        <PictureDetails>
            <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
            <GalleryURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMTY4/z/I~kAAOSwJb9WsVh9/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</GalleryURL>
            <PhotoDisplay>None</PhotoDisplay>
            <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMTY4/z/I~kAAOSwJb9WsVh9/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>
            <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFg5NDM=/z/l8sAAOSwpzdWsVie/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ProxyItem>false</ProxyItem>
        <BuyerGuaranteePrice currencyID="USD">20000.0</BuyerGuaranteePrice>
        <IntangibleItem>false</IntangibleItem>
        <ReturnPolicy>
            <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsNotAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
            <ReturnsAccepted>No returns accepted</ReturnsAccepted>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <ConditionID>4000</ConditionID>
        <ConditionDescription>Book is used but in good shape. May contain scribbles and/or notes in the margins.</ConditionDescription>
        <ConditionDisplayName>Very Good</ConditionDisplayName>
        <PostCheckoutExperienceEnabled>false</PostCheckoutExperienceEnabled>
        <ShippingPackageDetails>
            <ShippingIrregular>false</ShippingIrregular>
            <ShippingPackage>PackageThickEnvelope</ShippingPackage>
            <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
            <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
        </ShippingPackageDetails>
        <RelistParentID>321997285555</RelistParentID>
        <HideFromSearch>false</HideFromSearch>
        <eBayPlus>false</eBayPlus>
        <eBayPlusEligible>false</eBayPlusEligible>
    </Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```